# Unable to register to the hub

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I am trying to bring the selenium Grid up and running in my local machine and the below is the command that i ran on my local machine.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://<IP>:4444/grid/register -host <IP>
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:06 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Nov 27, 2017 7:42:07 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote startRemoteServer
WARNING: error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.No route to host (Host unreachable)
19:42:07.460 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11
19:42:07.464 INFO - OS: Linux 4.10.0-38-generic amd64
19:42:07.477 INFO - v2.28.0, with Core v2.28.0. Built from revision 18309
19:42:07.582 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub
19:42:07.583 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
19:42:07.584 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
19:42:07.586 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1d8d30f7
19:42:07.587 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
19:42:07.587 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-
```

Also, i am facing the same issue while running the above command in my Virtual machine as well.

Comment: are you able to ping to the hub from node machine/Virtual machine ?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh yes i am able to ping to the hub from Machine/Virtual Machine.

Comment: run this command on your VM : *java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://<hubIP>:4444/grid/register*